# Querystring not working, ampersands converted to %20

Tags: c#, query-string, urlencode

I have the following problem in C#, when I pass values with the querystring from an email like this:

http://www.website.com?firstname=Joe&lastname=Average

The values are shown on the website like this:

http://www.website.com?firstname%3d%24Joe%24%26lastname%3d%24Average

So basically the URL's are being encoded, but some parts shouldn't be encoded. I've tried `&amp;` instead of `&`, but no luck either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any values passed to/from URL should be Url Encoded/Decoded.
On the other hand when displaying text on the page (HTML) you should use `HtmlEncode`.

You can find the methods in namespace `System.Web`:

- `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.
- `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`.
- `HttpUtility.UrlHtmlEncode`.

etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're encoding entire querystring, and not only their *values*.
You should do something like

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("firstname", "Joe");
values.Add("lastname", "Average");
var querystring = String.Join("&", values.Select(pair => 
    pair.Key + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Value)).ToArray());
```